# SwiftUI ScrollView scroll to top

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

Is it possible to scroll to the top of a ScrollView in SwiftUI from the tap of a button?

From what I've read so far it sounds like it's not, yet if I tap the status bar it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not. Let's anticipate upcoming WWDC to come up with enhanced SwiftUI.